# Drop shadow on background color

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors

I am trying to drop shadow on a wpf datagrid row background color
What i tried is to set the datagrid row style but i`m kinda stuck there
I can set the background property to some color or even a gradient color, but i can't seem to drop shadow on that color
I am trying to make the row background less flat

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="....." />
```

Comment: Can you give us a picture of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Something like this: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ZVH.png) but only with grid rows, my row color is a binded property so i need the shadow to drop on whatever color the row have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="50" Color="{Binding color}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Although I don't know what you're trying to accomplish; the drop shadows from each row blend into each other and obscure the row text :-/

[image]